# Minimum size of a subarray that it's sum is equal to or larger than target

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have to find minimum size of a subarray that it's sum is equal to or larger than target using sliding window algorithm. Is this good enough in terms of complexity and how can I improve this, especially how could I improve the minLength assignment?

```
var minSubArrayLen = function(target, nums) {
    let minLength = 100000000000;
    let left = 0;
    let sum = 0;

    for(let i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        sum += nums[i];

        while(sum>=target) {
            minLength = Math.min(minLength, i-left+1);
            sum -= nums[left];
            left++;
        }
    }

    if(left===0) {
        minLength = 0;
    }

    return minLength;
};

let target = 7;
let nums = [2,3,1,2,4,3];

console.log(minSubArrayLen(target, nums));
```

It should log 2 to the console

Comment: This prints 0 for target 5 and nums [-1, 2, 3]. The answer should be 2, no?

Comment: updated my answer with a sliding window for negative numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can compact the code a bit plus add returning immediately if `minLength === 1`.

Regarding the comments of using negative values - you cannot use your sliding window since the window is broken with the negative numbers.

```js
var minSubArrayLen = function(target, nums) {

    let minLength = -1, left = 0, sum = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        sum += nums[i]
        while(sum >= target) {
            const candidate = i - left + 1;
            if(minLength > candidate || minLength < 0 ) minLength = candidate;
            if(minLength === 1) return 1;
            sum -= nums[left++];
        }
    }
    return minLength === -1 ? 0 : minLength; 
};

console.log(minSubArrayLen(5, [0,2,2,1,3,2]));
```